NO FUNCIONA LA SELECCION DE OBJETOS DE FABRIC.JS-CANVA
Llevo un tiempo probando distintas soluciones, pero no logro hacer que el menú de opciones de modificación del texto se muestre al seleccionar un cuadro de texto en el canvas. El problema es que no entra ni siquiera en el primer console.log de la función asociada al evento object:selected, lo que me hace pensar que hay algo mal en la obtención del objeto que está siendo seleccionado.
He revisado cómo estoy configurando el evento y he probado varias formas de obtener el objeto activo, usando canvas.getActiveObject() y verificando el tipo de objeto (como textbox para los cuadros de texto), pero parece que no se dispara el evento cuando selecciono el texto.
Sospecho que podría estar ocurriendo una de las siguientes cosas:
El evento object:selected no se está vinculando correctamente al canvas, por lo que no detecta cuándo un objeto es seleccionado.
El objeto fabric.textbox no se está seleccionando bien cuando lo añado al canvas, lo que impide que el evento sea disparado.
La lógica de selección podría estar interferida por otros eventos o scripts en mi proyecto, aunque no he encontrado ninguna interferencia obvia.
He probado soluciones alternativas, como añadir un objeto invisible alrededor del texto para mejorar la selección, pero aún así no consigo que el menú aparezca.
Si tienes alguna idea o has enfrentado un problema similar con Fabric.js, agradecería cualquier sugerencia. ¡Estoy abierto a probar más cosas!
Saludos.
CSS
    #opciones_texto{
            display: none;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 55px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
    }
    
    #opciones_imagen{
        display: none;
        height: 55px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
    }
        
 

JS
//================CANVAS================
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
//==== AÑADIR IMAGEN PRINCIPAL =====
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('principal_file_img');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                fabric.Image.fromURL(event.target.result, (img) => {
                    const containerWidth = document.getElementById('canvas_container').clientWidth;
                    const scale = containerWidth / img.width;

                    canvas.setWidth(containerWidth);
                    canvas.setHeight(img.height * scale); // Ajustar altura manteniendo relación de aspecto
                    img.set({
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        scaleX: scale,
                        scaleY: scale,
                        selectable: false, // Permitir selección y movimiento
                        evented: true 
                    });

                    canvas.clear(); // Limpia el canvas antes de agregar la nueva imagen
                    canvas.add(img);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });

    // Ajustar el canvas y la imagen al redimensionar la ventana
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        const containerWidth = document.getElementById('canvas_container').clientWidth;
        const currentImage = canvas.item(0);
        if (currentImage) {
            const scale = containerWidth / currentImage.width;
            canvas.setWidth(containerWidth);
            canvas.setHeight(currentImage.height * scale); // Mantener relación de aspecto
            currentImage.scaleX = scale; // Redimensionar la imagen
            currentImage.scaleY = scale; // Redimensionar la imagen
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });

//==== AÑADIR TEXTO =====

    document.getElementById('btn_text').addEventListener('click', function() {
        const text = new fabric.Textbox('Haz clic para escribir', {
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            fontSize: 16,
            opacity: 1,
            editable: true
        });
        canvas.add(text);
        canvas.setActiveObject(text);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

//==== AÑADIR IMG =====

    document.getElementById('btn_file_img').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
                    img.scale(0.1); // Escalar imagen al 10% de su tamaño original
    
                    img.set({
                        left: 10,
                        top: 10,
                        opacity: 1,
                    });
    
                    canvas.add(img);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });

//==== MOSTRAR MENUS =====
const cont_texo_opc = document.querySelector("#opciones_texto");
const cont_img_opc = document.querySelector("#opciones_imagen");
// Verifica si el evento 'mouse:down' está funcionando en general
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(event) {
    console.log('Mouse down en el canvas');
});

// Evento 'object:selected' en el canvas
canvas.on('object:selected', function(event) {
    const activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(); // Obtén el objeto activo
    console.log('Intentando seleccionar un objeto.');

    if (activeObject) {
        console.log('Tipo de objeto:', activeObject.type); // Muestra el tipo de objeto

        if (activeObject.type === 'textbox') {
            cont_texo_opc.style.display = 'flex'; // Muestra el contenedor para texto
        } else {
            cont_texo_opc.style.display = 'none'; // Oculta si no es un textbox
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No hay objeto seleccionado.'); // Mensaje si no hay selección
        cont_texo_opc.style.display = 'none'; // Oculta el contenedor
    }
});
    

